# When the data from Prisma is filtered by GraphQL, it ignores the remaining redundant data

Tags: graphql, nestjs, prisma

When I use Prisma and GraphQL, I realized that when a model is getting its data, it comes in areas other than the ones specified in the request, this is tiring the server, is it true?

**Requested data query**

[image: Requested data query]

**Response in the debug**

[image: Response in the debug]

Answer (score 0):

I founded a solution you can use https://paljs.com/ package, Package is has Prisma select tools